# python alternative package setup using setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools

I am having some trouble adding packages with my particular setup:

```
.
├── pkg_a
│   ├── pkg_a
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── module_a.py
│   └── run_a.py
├── pkg_b
│   ├── pkg_b
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── module_b.py
│   └── run_b.py
└── setup.py
```

My goal is to be able to import package modules without repeating package name twice.
For example, in `run_a.py` I'd like to be able to call `from pkg_a import module_a` instead of calling `from pkg_a.pkg_a import module_a`

I tried to follow Section 2.1 of doc [here](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-whole-packages). By creating `setup.py` as follow:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="test",
    packages=['pkg_a', 'pkg_b'],
    package_dir={'pkg_a':'pkg_a/pkg_a', 'pkg_b':'pkg_b/pkg_b'}
)
```

But this does not achieve the desired effect as mentioned above as I tried to call `python setup.py develop` and then `python -c 'from pkg_a import module_a'`.
Is this particular setup achievable? And what am I messing up here? Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

`package_dir` modifications do not work with *editable* (aka *develop*) installations. The only acceptable `package_dir` modification for *editable* installations is the one that covers the so-called *`src`-layout*:

```
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
```

Comment: You are right! I was able to call import successfully after doing `python setup.py install` instead. Thank you!

Comment: But if I want to be able to run `run_a.py` during development time with the desired import paths, is there other options? I can think of adding those paths to PYTHONPATH, but that seems a bit extreme.

Comment: I am very much against modifications to `sys.path` or `PYTHONPATH` in general. But if you know what you're doing and you're careful, maybe it's a case where it could be a good trick to add those directories to `PYTHONPATH`. On the other hand, looking at your project's directory structure I have doubts about the whole thing again. Do you mind editing your question to show the hierarchical structure of import modules and import packages that you want to have in the end? For example: are `run_a` and `run_b` supposed to become top-level modules?