# pip install bug with `-e` flag and `setuptools.setup(package_dir=...)` parameter?

Tags: python, pip

I have what I think is a pip bug, and I want to double-check that it's not actually a mistake of mine before submitting it as a formal issue. If it's not a bug, I'd appreciate an explanation of what I'm doing wrong.

I have a project structure like so:

```
project/
  setup.py

  project_src/
    __init__.py
    ...

  common_utils/
    utils_src/
      __init__.py
      ...
```

I want to be able to:

- import code from "project/project_src" via `import project_src` (this isn't the issue, I just want to be comprehensive)
- import code from "project/common_utils/utils_src" via `import utils_src` (note this strips the "common_utils" folder from the package path name)

In order to do this, the root-level "setup.py" looks something like this (abbreviated):

```py
# setup.py
import setuptools


setuptools.setup(
    ...,
    packages=['project_src', 'utils_src'],
    package_dir={
        'project_src': 'project_src',
        'utils_src': 'common_utils/utils_src',
    },
    ...,
)
```

Now *here's* my issue. When I then install this package locally via CL as `pip install project/`, I can then open an interpreter and successfully run `import project_src` *and* `import utils_src`. But if I install via `pip install -e project/`, `import project_src` works but `import utils_src` triggers a `ModuleNotFoundError` error. (This is a huge pain as I rely on using the `-e` flag for development.)

Again, please let me know if this appears to be a bug, or if this is a mistake on my part.

Comment: In short; `package_dir` modifications are incompatible with the `develop` or `editable` installation modes. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65595005

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out this is a long-standing issue: [pypa/setuptools #230: develop mode does not respect src structure](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/230)

Thanks @sinoroc for the hint @ comments on this answer

Comment: This is not true. `package_dir` allow the so-called _`src`-layout_. If that is the only `package_dir` modification that you want to do, then it is feasible, and it works with the _editable_ installation. -- But what you want to do is more complicated than that apparently.

Comment: @sinoroc I don't see the difference between what I said in this answer, and what you commented on the original question. also what is the "so-called src layout"? if I'm not explaining this properly, please post your own answer and explain it yourself

Comment: My comment on the original question was not precise enough: There is one and only one `package_dir` modification that is compatible with `python setup.py develop` (and `pip install --editable .`), and that modification is: `package_dir={'': 'src'}`, where `src` can be any relative path to a sub-directory. Anything else will cause issues with the _develop_ installation mode. -- And it is exactly what is needed for the "src layout" -- This article talks about the src layout: https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/05/25/python-packaging/

Answer (score 1):

Not a bug in `pip`, your mistake. You want to use `common_utils/` directory as a parent dir for a package but you want `utils_src` as a package inside it. So change your `setup.py`:

```
package_dir={
    'project_src': 'project_src',
    'utils_src': 'common_utils',
},
```

With this `utils_src` will be installed as a top-level package so you can do

```
import utils_src
```

PS. They say this doesn't work with

```
pip install -e
```

I didn't test the rumor yet.

Comment: this doesn't fix my problem; I'm still seeing the same `ModuleNotFound` error when running `import utils_src`. I also don't understand the symmetry mismatch between how project_src's and utils_src's directories are specified

Comment: this also doesn't explain why I get different results with and without the `-e` flag

Comment: @phd Important to note that this won't work with `pip install --editable ...` though (if I am not mistaken).

Comment: @sinoroc Thanks, I added a PS. Needs to be tested…